# Numpy : Array is larger than the maximum possible size

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video

I'm trying to run the Python code for Eulerian vide magnification  (https://github.com/brycedrennan/eulerian-magnification) and when I run the code to replicate the study, I get the following error: `ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size.`

The error occrurs at:
     `vid_frames = numpy.zeros((frame_count, height, width, 3), dtype='uint8')`

When I do frame_count * height * width * 3 = 2326579200 = 2.3265792 Gb

According to the Task Manager, I have 12.5GB still available. That should be enough for at least one video, right ?

Here is the full traceback :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liama\Desktop\Test_VID_MAG2\replicate_study.py", line 93, in <module>
    replicate_study()
  File "C:\Users\liama\Desktop\Test_VID_MAG2\replicate_study.py", line 78, in replicate_study
    vid, fps = load_video_float(source_path)
  File "C:\Users\liama\Desktop\Test_VID_MAG2\eulerian_magnification\io.py", line 43, in load_video_float
    vid_data, fps = _load_video(video_filename)
  File "C:\Users\liama\Desktop\Test_VID_MAG2\eulerian_magnification\io.py", line 29, in _load_video
    vid_frames = numpy.zeros((frame_count, height, width, 3), dtype='uint8')
ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size.`

What could be causing this error ?

Thank.

Comment: I haven't seen this error before.  This is different from the usual memory error.  Show the full traceback.

Comment: @hpaulj I added the traceback

Comment: What's your Python? `numpy` version?  Computer?  OS?  32 bit by any chance?  `np.zeros(2326579200, dtype='uint8')` works for me, on a rather modest computer.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, you're right ! For some reason I had installed Python 32-bit on my 64-bit computer. I reinstalled Python and now it works.